# How can I load Jpeg image from disk and create video file (.avi etc) without using opencv in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to load JPEG images from disk and create video file from them but I am unable to do this. I was successful in creating video file of BITMAP Images by using HBITMAP handler but the size of Bitmap Images is mush greater so I want to make video with Jpeg Images.

here is my class for converting bmp images to avi file:

```
#define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <vfw.h>

#include "avi_utils.h"


// First, we'll define the WAV file format.
#include <pshpack1.h>
typedef struct
{ char id[4];         //="fmt "
  unsigned long size; //=16
  short wFormatTag;   //=WAVE_FORMAT_PCM=1
  unsigned short wChannels;       //=1 or 2 for mono or stereo
  unsigned long dwSamplesPerSec;  //=11025 or 22050 or 44100
  unsigned long dwAvgBytesPerSec; //=wBlockAlign * dwSamplesPerSec
  unsigned short wBlockAlign;     //=wChannels * (wBitsPerSample==8?1:2)
  unsigned short wBitsPerSample;  //=8 or 16, for bits per sample
} FmtChunk;

typedef struct
{ char id[4];            //="data"
  unsigned long size;    //=datsize, size of the following array
  unsigned char data[1]; //=the raw data goes here
} DataChunk;

typedef struct
{ char id[4];         //="RIFF"
  unsigned long size; //=datsize+8+16+4
  char type[4];       //="WAVE"
  FmtChunk fmt;
  DataChunk dat;
} WavChunk;
#include <poppack.h>




// This is the internal structure represented by the HAVI handle:
typedef struct
{ IAVIFile *pfile;    // created by CreateAvi
  WAVEFORMATEX wfx;   // as given to CreateAvi (.nChanels=0 if none was given). Used when audio stream is first created.
  int period;         // specified in CreateAvi, used when the video stream is first created
  IAVIStream *as;     // audio stream, initialised when audio stream is first created
  IAVIStream *ps, *psCompressed;  // video stream, when first created
  unsigned long nframe, nsamp;    // which frame will be added next, which sample will be added next
  bool iserr;         // if true, then no function will do anything
} TAviUtil;





HAVI CreateAvi(const char *fn, int frameperiod, const WAVEFORMATEX *wfx)
{ IAVIFile *pfile;
  AVIFileInit();
  HRESULT hr = AVIFileOpen(&pfile, fn, OF_WRITE|OF_CREATE, NULL);
  if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {AVIFileExit(); return NULL;}
  TAviUtil *au = new TAviUtil;
  au->pfile = pfile;
  if (wfx==NULL) ZeroMemory(&au->wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)); else CopyMemory(&au->wfx,wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
  au->period = frameperiod;
  au->as=0; au->ps=0; au->psCompressed=0;
  au->nframe=0; au->nsamp=0;
  au->iserr=false;
  return (HAVI)au;
}

HRESULT CloseAvi(HAVI avi)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
  TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
  if (au->as!=0) AVIStreamRelease(au->as); au->as=0;
  if (au->psCompressed!=0) AVIStreamRelease(au->psCompressed); au->psCompressed=0;
  if (au->ps!=0) AVIStreamRelease(au->ps); au->ps=0;
  if (au->pfile!=0) AVIFileRelease(au->pfile); au->pfile=0;
  AVIFileExit();
  delete au;
  return S_OK;
}


HRESULT SetAviVideoCompression(HAVI avi, HBITMAP hbm, AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS *opts, bool ShowDialog, HWND hparent)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
  if (hbm==NULL) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
  DIBSECTION dibs; int sbm = GetObject(hbm,sizeof(dibs),&dibs);
  if (sbm!=sizeof(DIBSECTION)) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
  TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
  if (au->iserr) return AVIERR_ERROR;
  if (au->psCompressed!=0) return AVIERR_COMPRESSOR;
  //
  if (au->ps==0) // create the stream, if it wasn't there before
  { AVISTREAMINFO strhdr; ZeroMemory(&strhdr,sizeof(strhdr));
    strhdr.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;// stream type
    strhdr.fccHandler = 0; 
    strhdr.dwScale = au->period;
    strhdr.dwRate = 1000;
    strhdr.dwSuggestedBufferSize  = dibs.dsBmih.biSizeImage;
    SetRect(&strhdr.rcFrame, 0, 0, dibs.dsBmih.biWidth, dibs.dsBmih.biHeight);
    HRESULT hr=AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->ps, &strhdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  }
  //
  if (au->psCompressed==0) // set the compression, prompting dialog if necessary
  { AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS myopts; ZeroMemory(&myopts,sizeof(myopts));
    AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS *aopts[1];
    if (opts!=NULL) aopts[0]=opts; else aopts[0]=&myopts;
    if (ShowDialog)
    { BOOL res = (BOOL)AVISaveOptions(hparent,0,1,&au->ps,aopts);
      if (!res) {AVISaveOptionsFree(1,aopts); au->iserr=true; return AVIERR_USERABORT;}
    }
    HRESULT hr = AVIMakeCompressedStream(&au->psCompressed, au->ps, aopts[0], NULL);
    AVISaveOptionsFree(1,aopts);
    if (hr != AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    DIBSECTION dibs; GetObject(hbm,sizeof(dibs),&dibs);
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(au->psCompressed, 0, &dibs.dsBmih, dibs.dsBmih.biSize+dibs.dsBmih.biClrUsed*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  }
  //
  return AVIERR_OK;
}


HRESULT AddAviFrame(HAVI avi, HBITMAP hbm)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
  if (hbm==NULL) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
  DIBSECTION dibs; int sbm = GetObject(hbm,sizeof(dibs),&dibs);
  if (sbm!=sizeof(DIBSECTION)) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
  TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
  if (au->iserr) return AVIERR_ERROR;
  //
  if (au->ps==0) // create the stream, if it wasn't there before
  { AVISTREAMINFO strhdr; ZeroMemory(&strhdr,sizeof(strhdr));
    strhdr.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;// stream type
    strhdr.fccHandler = 0; 
    strhdr.dwScale = au->period;
    strhdr.dwRate = 1000;
    strhdr.dwSuggestedBufferSize  = dibs.dsBmih.biSizeImage;
    SetRect(&strhdr.rcFrame, 0, 0, dibs.dsBmih.biWidth, dibs.dsBmih.biHeight);
    HRESULT hr=AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->ps, &strhdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  }
  //
  // create an empty compression, if the user hasn't set any
  if (au->psCompressed==0)
  { AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS opts; ZeroMemory(&opts,sizeof(opts));
    opts.fccHandler=mmioFOURCC('D','I','B',' '); 
    HRESULT hr = AVIMakeCompressedStream(&au->psCompressed, au->ps, &opts, NULL);
    if (hr != AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(au->psCompressed, 0, &dibs.dsBmih, dibs.dsBmih.biSize+dibs.dsBmih.biClrUsed*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  }
  //
  //Now we can add the frame
  HRESULT hr = AVIStreamWrite(au->psCompressed, au->nframe, 1, dibs.dsBm.bmBits, dibs.dsBmih.biSizeImage, AVIIF_KEYFRAME, NULL, NULL);
  if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  au->nframe++; return S_OK;
}



HRESULT AddAviAudio(HAVI avi, void *dat, unsigned long numbytes)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
  if (dat==NULL || numbytes==0) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
  TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
  if (au->iserr) return AVIERR_ERROR;
  if (au->wfx.nChannels==0) return AVIERR_BADFORMAT;
  unsigned long numsamps = numbytes*8 / au->wfx.wBitsPerSample;
  if ((numsamps*au->wfx.wBitsPerSample/8)!=numbytes) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
  //
  if (au->as==0) // create the stream if necessary
  { AVISTREAMINFO ahdr; ZeroMemory(&ahdr,sizeof(ahdr));
    ahdr.fccType=streamtypeAUDIO;
    ahdr.dwScale=au->wfx.nBlockAlign;
    ahdr.dwRate=au->wfx.nSamplesPerSec*au->wfx.nBlockAlign; 
    ahdr.dwSampleSize=au->wfx.nBlockAlign;
    ahdr.dwQuality=(DWORD)-1;
    HRESULT hr = AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->as, &ahdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(au->as,0,&au->wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  }
  //
  // now we can write the data
  HRESULT hr = AVIStreamWrite(au->as,au->nsamp,numsamps,dat,numbytes,0,NULL,NULL);
  if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  au->nsamp+=numsamps; return S_OK;
}



HRESULT AddAviWav(HAVI avi, const char *src, DWORD flags)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
  if (flags!=SND_MEMORY && flags!=SND_FILENAME) return AVIERR_BADFLAGS;
  if (src==0) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
  TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
  if (au->iserr) return AVIERR_ERROR;
  //
  char *buf=0; WavChunk *wav = (WavChunk*)src;
  if (flags==SND_FILENAME)
  { HANDLE hf=CreateFile(src,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);
    if (hf==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {au->iserr=true; return AVIERR_FILEOPEN;}
    DWORD size = GetFileSize(hf,NULL);
    buf = new char[size];
    DWORD red; ReadFile(hf,buf,size,&red,NULL);
    CloseHandle(hf);
    wav = (WavChunk*)buf;
  }
  //
  // check that format doesn't clash
  bool badformat=false;
  if (au->wfx.nChannels==0)
  { au->wfx.wFormatTag=wav->fmt.wFormatTag;
    au->wfx.cbSize=0;
    au->wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec=wav->fmt.dwAvgBytesPerSec;
    au->wfx.nBlockAlign=wav->fmt.wBlockAlign;
    au->wfx.nChannels=wav->fmt.wChannels;
    au->wfx.nSamplesPerSec=wav->fmt.dwSamplesPerSec;
    au->wfx.wBitsPerSample=wav->fmt.wBitsPerSample;
  }
  else
  { if (au->wfx.wFormatTag!=wav->fmt.wFormatTag) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec!=wav->fmt.dwAvgBytesPerSec) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.nBlockAlign!=wav->fmt.wBlockAlign) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.nChannels!=wav->fmt.wChannels) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.nSamplesPerSec!=wav->fmt.dwSamplesPerSec) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.wBitsPerSample!=wav->fmt.wBitsPerSample) badformat=true;
  }
  if (badformat) {if (buf!=0) delete[] buf; return AVIERR_BADFORMAT;}
  //
  if (au->as==0) // create the stream if necessary
  { AVISTREAMINFO ahdr; ZeroMemory(&ahdr,sizeof(ahdr));
    ahdr.fccType=streamtypeAUDIO;
    ahdr.dwScale=au->wfx.nBlockAlign;
    ahdr.dwRate=au->wfx.nSamplesPerSec*au->wfx.nBlockAlign; 
    ahdr.dwSampleSize=au->wfx.nBlockAlign;
    ahdr.dwQuality=(DWORD)-1;
    HRESULT hr = AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->as, &ahdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {if (buf!=0) delete[] buf; au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(au->as,0,&au->wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {if (buf!=0) delete[] buf; au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  }
  //
  // now we can write the data
  unsigned long numbytes = wav->dat.size;
  unsigned long numsamps = numbytes*8 / au->wfx.wBitsPerSample;
  HRESULT hr = AVIStreamWrite(au->as,au->nsamp,numsamps,wav->dat.data,numbytes,0,NULL,NULL);
  if (buf!=0) delete[] buf;
  if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  au->nsamp+=numsamps; return S_OK;
}



unsigned int FormatAviMessage(HRESULT code, char *buf,unsigned int len)
{ const char *msg="unknown avi result code";
  switch (code)
  { case S_OK: msg="Success"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADFORMAT: msg="AVIERR_BADFORMAT: corrupt file or unrecognized format"; break;
    case AVIERR_MEMORY: msg="AVIERR_MEMORY: insufficient memory"; break;
    case AVIERR_FILEREAD: msg="AVIERR_FILEREAD: disk error while reading file"; break;
    case AVIERR_FILEOPEN: msg="AVIERR_FILEOPEN: disk error while opening file"; break;
    case REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG: msg="REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG: file type not recognised"; break;
    case AVIERR_READONLY: msg="AVIERR_READONLY: file is read-only"; break;
    case AVIERR_NOCOMPRESSOR: msg="AVIERR_NOCOMPRESSOR: a suitable compressor could not be found"; break;
    case AVIERR_UNSUPPORTED: msg="AVIERR_UNSUPPORTED: compression is not supported for this type of data"; break;
    case AVIERR_INTERNAL: msg="AVIERR_INTERNAL: internal error"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADFLAGS: msg="AVIERR_BADFLAGS"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADPARAM: msg="AVIERR_BADPARAM"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADSIZE: msg="AVIERR_BADSIZE"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADHANDLE: msg="AVIERR_BADHANDLE"; break;
    case AVIERR_FILEWRITE: msg="AVIERR_FILEWRITE: disk error while writing file"; break;
    case AVIERR_COMPRESSOR: msg="AVIERR_COMPRESSOR"; break;
    case AVIERR_NODATA: msg="AVIERR_READONLY"; break;
    case AVIERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL: msg="AVIERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL"; break;
    case AVIERR_CANTCOMPRESS: msg="AVIERR_CANTCOMPRESS"; break;
    case AVIERR_USERABORT: msg="AVIERR_USERABORT"; break;
    case AVIERR_ERROR: msg="AVIERR_ERROR"; break;
  }
  unsigned int mlen=(unsigned int)strlen(msg);
  if (buf==0 || len==0) return mlen;
  unsigned int n=mlen; if (n+1>len) n=len-1;
  strncpy(buf,msg,n); buf[n]=0;
  return mlen;
}
```

Here is my main:

```
int main ()
{
    const char *fns[] = {"1.bmp","2.bmp","3.bmp","4.bmp","5.bmp"};

    HAVI avi = CreateAvi("test.avi",1000/5,NULL);
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(fns)/sizeof(fns[0]); i++)
    { 
        HBITMAP hbm=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,fns[i],IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
        AddAviFrame(avi,hbm);
        DeleteObject(hbm);
    }
    AddAviWav(avi,"wav.wav",SND_FILENAME);
    CloseAvi(avi);


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2829113/1180785

Comment: (that's using ffmpeg but it looks like invoking ffmpeg with `exec` or similar would be enough here)

Comment: How did you create a video out of BMP files? What type of video?

Comment: If you just need a way to convert a bunch of images into a video, take a look at [MonkeyJam](http://monkeyjam.org/).  I haven't used it recently, but I used it a few years ago for some LEGOmation, and it worked beautifully.

Comment: I dont want any form . I need it done in console application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details. What type of video did you make with Bitmap files? And how?

To create a video, frames (or images) must be given in uncompressed form.

For the same image, Bitmap and JPEG occupy the same space when they are uncompressed. So what you need to do is decode the JPEGs one by one, and pass them to some video codec like Xvid or x264 which compresses the stream. Although I don't know how you'll store that stream into the AVI container (which uses the RIFF format, btw).

Decoding JPEG files isn't as easy as Bitmap, I recommend using a library. For example, libjpeg. http://www.ijg.org/

**EDIT:** In a nutshell, reading JPEG instead of Bitmap will be of no use. What I suggest is that do what you are doing right now, and later compress the video using a library like **ffmpeg** http://www.ffmpeg.org or **libav** http://libav.org/. I'm sure you will find usage examples by searching. Good luck!

Comment: @user1520862 The video produced is uncompressed right? Check the metadata on it once. You could use VLC to do that. Uncompressed is always huge. Even if you decode JPEGs and create a video out of them, they would still be equally huge.

Comment: As jpeg is much smaller in size than bmp I want to create the video with jpeg as I have to transfer it from one pc to another through LAN. is there a way that I can edit this code for JPEG?

Comment: jpeg files are smaller on disk because they are compressed, but you're creating a video of uncompressed frames.  Any file format you're reading from will result in the same size video because of that.  If you want a smaller video you'll need to use a compressed video format as the answer explains.